# Making a swap function from selection sort

Tags: python-3.x

this is part of a long code. How do I change the swapping of the selection sort into a global function?

```
def SortByGenre(G):
    for i in range (len(G)-1):
        minimum = i
        mingenre = G[minimum][2]
        price = G[minimum][3]
        artist = G[minimum][1]
        title = G[minimum][0]
        for j in range (i+1, len(G)):
            if mingenre > G[j][2]:
                mingenre = G[j][2]
                price = G[j][3]
                artist = G[j][1]
                title = G[j][0]
                minimum = j

        tempgenre = G[i][2]
        tempprice = G[i][3]
        tempartist = G[i][1]
        temptitle = G[i][0]
        G[i][2] = mingenre
        G[i][3] = price
        G[i][1] = artist
        G[i][0] = title
        G[minimum][2] = tempgenre
        G[minimum][3] = tempprice
        G[minimum][1] = tempartist
        G[minimum][0] = temptitle
    return G
```

I want to make this part into a global function that i can use for the other parts of my program:

```
        tempgenre = G[i][2]
        tempprice = G[i][3]
        tempartist = G[i][1]
        temptitle = G[i][0]
        G[i][2] = mingenre
        G[i][3] = price
        G[i][1] = artist
        G[i][0] = title
        G[minimum][2] = tempgenre
        G[minimum][3] = tempprice
        G[minimum][1] = tempartist
        G[minimum][0] = temptitle
```

Comment: What on earth do you mean by a "global function"?

Comment: do you mean you want the function to create a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) of the list before editing it?

Comment: it means i can use that function if i were to call it up from another selection sort function. My program consists of several selection sort functions, that's why i want the swap function to be able to be called up from any of them.

Comment: if the function is declared in the global name space (the `def` is in the main body of the module) all other functions / classes / methods can make use of it...